Folder Creation and File Saving
I am trying to write code that allows me to create a new folder based on the value of a cell in the existing workbook.  From there, save a copy of the file in the newly created workbook with a name based on cell value as well, plus some additional text added.  Please see below code and let me know where I am failing.  The error is highlighting the 'ActiveWorkBook.SaveCopyAs' line.
Dim path As String
Dim filename1 As String
Dim filename2 As String 

path = ThisWorkbook.path & "\"

filename1 = Worksheets("Instructions").Range("B1").Text & " Initial Comment Matrix"
filename2 = Worksheets("Instructions").Range("B1").Text

MkDir filename2

Application.DisplayAlerts = False
ActiveWorkbook.SaveCopyAs ThisWorkbook.path & filename2 & filename1 & ".xlsm"
Application.DisplayAlerts = True

Application.ScreenUpdating = True

MsgBox ("DONE")


You forgot to add the path separator: ThisWorkbook.path & "\" & filename2 &  "\" & filename1 & ".xlsm" or path & filename2 &  "\" & filename1 & ".xlsm"

Also use the full path when calling MkDir    You're using both ActiveWorkbook and ThisWorkbook - are those the same workbook?

Yes, same workbook.  So the code creates the Folder in the same file path with the correct name, but it fails to save the document.  Says the path doesnt exist, may have been deleted or removed.  I was hoping it would recognize the new folder and save the copy into it.

Let's say path = "C:\Test\" and B1 = "MyFolder". What is the expected file path? Is it e.g. C:\Test\MyFolder\MyFolder Initial Comment Matrix.xlsm or something else?

VBasic.  Yes, the location of the ActiveWorkBook is where the "B1" folder is created and in that "B1" Folder the the .xlsm would be copied with the Initial Comment Matrix file in it.  Currently, I have the folder successfully creating but it is not saving the copy in the new folder.  Errors out.

Like this:
Dim v As String, path As String, wb As Workbook

Set wb = ThisWorkbook
v = wb.Worksheets("Instructions").Range("B1").text
path = wb.path & "\" & v

If Dir(path, vbDirectory) = "" Then MkDir path 'use the full path

Application.DisplayAlerts = False
wb.SaveCopyAs path & "\" & v & " Initial Comment Matrix.xlsm"
Application.DisplayAlerts = True


What do you mean by use the Full path name?  Thats my main issue, this is going to be used dynamically.  The path is essentially where the file is at now.  It wont be the same.

MkDir "blah" is "create a folder named 'blah' in the current directory".  What is the current directory here?  It may not be what you think/expect, so it's best to be specific by using the full path (wb.path & "\" & v), as I did above.

I guess I am not fully understanding, this code errors on the line where you have 'use the full path.  I am not sure what I am supposed to put in place of 'use the full path.

That’s just a comment - it’s not intending for you to replace it with some thing.  What’s the error you’re getting there?  Is wb.path a local drive?

Add Debug.Print path and make sure it looks OK
